# HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found when export from crystal report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i have configured my iis and hosted the application. all it works fine except crystal report.
VS2008 is am using with sql2008 r2.My os is windows 7 and iis7 am using.crystal report 10.5.0.1943 is am using.

crystal report's tool bar is not wage(ie shows 'submit query' instead of buttons)
when i click the export button am getting the error msg as follows.

HTTP ERROR 404.0-NOT FOUND

The resource u are looking for has been removed or changed its name,or it is temporarily unavailable.

i have googled and as mentioned installed CR runtime. but still the problem persists.

any help wil be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found it ...

Pls do one thing ..

go to >> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

then copy aspnet_client folder and paste it into the virtual directory you have created. its done......

thank you.