# Crystal report export/print option not working

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am having problem with export/print options in my  website ,aspnet_client folder is there in root of website. and also in root of wwwroot of inetpub folder but when i try to run crystal report , all toolbar images are not showing.

So i added property to toolbar

```
ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="~/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/images/toolbar/"/>
```

now images are showing but when i click on export/print

Its going to

```
http://localhost:2817/aspnet_client/System_Web/4_0_30319/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/html/crystalexportdialog.htm
```

and saying 404 error in abc website

1. These files are there in website as well as in wwwroot
2. It should not go to wwwroot of local it should go to websites aspnet_client folder ??

Please help me, i have tried following solutions but still no luck

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896213/http-error-404-0-not-found-when-export-from-crystal-report

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898590/crystal-report-viewer-print-export-buttons-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-app

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/275146/Crystal-Report-Export-button-Not-Working

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/418635/Print-Button-and-export-button-is-not-working-in-c
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy `"CrystalReportWebFormViewer4"` Folder from your

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319
```

folder and paste to this folder

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETClientFiles
```